# strrchr() function cause memory corruption

Tags: c

I'm just try to writing a little function to get extension of a file (char * *file*) using strrchr() (*string.h*).
But, I've a problem, this function cause a memory corruption error (and I don't know why precisly).

I already check the parameter *file*, it's OK.

I expect a result like ".jpg" when I put "01.jpg" in input.
When it's "" in input, i'm waiting "" in result.
And same when input is "NA"

```
char * getExtensionOfFile(char * file){
  //create variable ext
  char * ext = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4); 
  strcpy(ext,"");

  if(strlen(file)==0 || strcmp(file,"NA")==0) return ""; //If file is empty or useless (case file=="NA")

  sprintf(ext,"%s",strrchr(file,'.'));

  return ext;
```

I think the guilty is strrchr().
If it's true, why ? if not ? Which ?

I tried to rewrite this function from scratch with *char[]* instead but it's less beautiful and I really want to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: You need `5` bytes to store `.jpg`. One extra byte for the string NUL terminator. Also, `strchr` itself will never cause memory corruption. Though the way you use it might.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in a debugger to find out where things go wrong?

Comment: Tip: Never use buffer-size ignorant functions like `sprintf` that will gleefully stomp outside of your buffer bounds. Use things like [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) where you can tell it precisely how big your buffer is and it will error if there's an issue.

Comment: `return "";` results in a memory leak.

Comment: By definition, `sizeof(char)` is always one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after discutions with others persons, someone found a pretty (good?) solution.

Thanks for your help!

The solution (not by myself)

```c
const char * getExtensionOfFile(const char * file){
  if (strlen(file) == 0 || strcmp(file, "NA") == 0) return "";

  return strrchr(file,'.');
}
```

Comment: If the `.` is not found then NULL will be returned so the caller will have to deal with that ; you may want to consider returning `""` instead of NULL in taht case

Comment: @M.M More accurately, returning a pointer to the end of the input string which is equivalent to an empty string. `return ""` is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

suggest keeping it simple.

```
#include <string.h>

char * returnExtension( char * filename )
{
    char * ext;
    if( (ext = strchr( filename, '.'))
    {
        return ext;
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```